# SQLite: Unique insert issue

Tags: android, sqlite, unique, composite-primary-key

I have an issue inserting rows into a table with a compound primary key specified.

Compound key on:

```
_id = id of the series (this starts always with 0 for every new shooting)
shooting_id = id of my training session
program_id = id of discipline I am currently training
```

Whenever I try to insert a second row that has the same "_id" column value, I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO series(_id,shooting_id,rings,program_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)]:       UNIQUE constraint failed: series._id, series._id, series._id 05-19 08:36:05.070    2417-2417/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting _id=0 shooting_id=1 rings=100 program_id=0 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: series._id, series.program_id, series._id (code 2067)
```

Example:

```
// first training session
INSERT INTO series(_id,shooting_id,rings,program_id) VALUES (0,0,100,0)
INSERT INTO series(_id,shooting_id,rings,program_id) VALUES (1,0,98,0)
INSERT INTO series(_id,shooting_id,rings,program_id) VALUES (2,0,98,0)
// second training session --> only shooting_id has changed (!!)
INSERT INTO series(_id,shooting_id,rings,program_id) VALUES (0,1,100,0) <-- results in above error
```

The table is specified like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SERIES = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
+ TABLE_SERIES + " ("
+ COLUMN_SERIES_SHOOTING_ID + " integer NOT NULL, "
+ COLUMN_SERIES_PROGRAM_ID + " integer NOT NULL, "
+ COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " integer NOT NULL, "
+ COLUMN_SERIES_RINGS + " integer NOT NULL, "
+ "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_SERIES_SHOOTING_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_SHOOTING + "(_id), "
+ "UNIQUE (" + COLUMN_SHOOTING_ID + "," + COLUMN_SERIES_PROGRAM_ID + "," + COLUMN_SERIES_ID + "));";`
```

Why??   :-(

Comment: @Downvoter with deleted comment: "Because only the combination of all three columns is unique."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UNIQUE` constraint is wrong. The column name variables have `_id` from other tables, not the columns in the `series` table and the constraint becomes `(_id,_id,_id)`, not `(_id,shooting_id,program_id)`.